# TypeScript, Library:React-Time-Ago thinks it requires a number, I'm giving it a string. I cant figure out how to make it accept a number?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, timeago

```
       import ReactTimeAgo from "react-time-ago"

        <ReactTimeAgo 
        
          date = {tweet._createdAt}
          />
```

_createdAt outputs time as 2022-06-02T01:16:40Z

I'm using React-time-ago to change it into like 21 minutes ago. It actually works fine. Yet, TypeScript complains staying that date parameter needs to come in as a number. so i went into the index.d.ts and changed the type from number to any.

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    date: Date | any;
    future?: boolean;
    timeStyle?: string | Style;
    round?: string;
    minTimeLeft?: number;
    tooltip?: boolean;
    component?: React.ReactType;
    wrapperComponent?: React.ReactType;
    wrapperProps?: object;
    locale?: string;
    locales?: string[];
    formatVerboseDate?: (date: Date) => string;
    verboseDateFormat?: object;
```

That stopped the error for vscode, but it still shows up on the browser and my deployment fails because of that error. How do I get typescript to stop complaining about getting a string?

- it should be getting that string, if I give it a number, it gives the incorrect value. and I still get the error if I use @ts-ignore or @ts-nocheck. Seems to do nothing for me. Thanks for any help!

This is the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b85pA.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't try to change the library files manually.

The `date` property in this package accepts a union type of `Date` and `number`. So your best bet would be to convert the date string into a `Date` object before feeding the `date` property field. You can use a method like;

```
const creationDate: Date = new Date('2022-06-02T01:16:40Z')
```

To parse that date string into a date object and then give it as a prop.

By editing your direct example;

```
import ReactTimeAgo from "react-time-ago"

<ReactTimeAgo 
  date = {new Date(tweet._createdAt)}
/>
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Thank you so much. And note on the packages. still learning!